# Relationship with many to many

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, erd

I am trying to get a basic rails application running that helps capture the nutritional information of each food item from a list of food items. The nutritional information is stored per ingredient and calculated as the sum of individual ingredients.

Here is what I have so far:

Have two models Food and Ingredient. Each Food has many Ingredients and each Ingredient is used in many Food. The way I want to fix this is to break up the many-to-many with a table in between say Recipe which has the pk of Food and pk Ingredient. But my problem is that a Recipe can have many ingredients and an ingredient has many recipes. How do i split these two tables the best way so I can capture a food item and its list of ingredients? Or is there a better way to do the whole thing?

Say for the purposes of example Food has name, description and Ingredient has name, calories, nutrients.

Answer (score 2):

You need [has_many_through](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) association.

You will organize like:

```
class Food < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :recipes
  has_many :ingredients,
    through: :recipes
end

class Ingredient < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :recipes
  has_many :foods,
    through: :recipes
end

class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :food
  belongs_to :ingredient
end
```

This way, you can store additional info inside `Recipe`

Comment: The problem with this I face is that I cannot add a new recipe because a recipe can have many ingredients. I am still confused as to how I would populate this model.

Comment: One recipe would have 1 food, and 1 ingredient, it still is many to many, but with more fields

Comment: How do I populate the recipe table for say a chicken salad which has chicken, lettuce and tomato as ingredients? I would have 3 entries each having food item chicken salad and ingredients ranging from chicken to tomato? Is this table populated automatically with all the possible combinations of ingredients and food or is it to be manually added?